# Show that any two dilatations with the same center commute and show that their composition is another dilatation with the same center.

Tags: analytic-geometry

I need help to solve this question! Our teacher is gonna ask this on the exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so clear from your question, but I suppose that what you call a ''dilatation'' is an [homotetic transformation in an affine space.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation)

In this case let
the two transformations be:
$$
d_1(M)=S+\lambda_1 \overrightarrow {SM}
$$
$$
d_2(M)=S+\lambda_2 \overrightarrow {SM}
$$
where $S$ is the common fixed point and $\lambda_{1,2}$ the two scale factors, than we have:
$$
d_2\left(d_1(M)\right)=S+\lambda_2  \overrightarrow {Sd_1(M)}
$$
where:
$$
\overrightarrow {Sd_1(M)}=\lambda_1\overrightarrow {SM}
$$

so:
$$
d_2\left(d_1(M)\right)=S+\lambda_2  \lambda_1\overrightarrow {SM}
$$
is an homotetic transformation with the same fixed point $S$ and scale factor $\lambda_3=\lambda_1\lambda_2$

The commutativity is easily proved from this.